# Nopcommerce customization - CATEGORY-WISE PRICES & CUSTOMIZATION OF FILTERS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

Can any one help with following scenario? I am working on a car inventory, such that,

1) An end product is a car, but pricing differs as per city (due to road taxes etc.). User is expected to select a city and resulting car list should display  prices depending on location. Similarly a product details view should display price in selected location.

My initial approach was to have Cities as primary categories. Create a product called 'Car A' and map it to all cities since 'car A'  could be available in multiple cities. To take care of city wise pricing variation  - I can create multiple 'variants' under 'Car A' as per cities e.g. Product 'Car A' can have product variants 'Car A - City 1', 'Car A - City 2' and so on. 
However, if I am not wrong a variant can't be mapped directly to a category.

2) Product details view shows prices of ALL variants. Is there a way I can show price of only 'relevant' variant i.e. If user clicks on category 'City A' and then navigates to a product details view, I would want to show price for variant 'Car A City A'. I understand no such 1-to-1 one relationship exists between category and product variant, so any suggestions are most welcome.

3) I want to display 2 prices i.e. Ex-showroom and Monthly lease. So I am planning to replicate the price entity. I want to know if it's possible to enable functionality of 'price filter' to 'lease filter' i.e. I need to have two price filters Ex-showroom and Monthly lease

4) Lastly, has any one successfully customized the default spec filters to checkboxes or drop-downs.  I tried nop-templates Ajax Filters. It's a nice plugin. However I need a lot of customization like having two sets of price filters (ex-showroom & lease).

**I fully understand that above will need lot of customization and I am open for it. However, any suggestions or prior experiences might get me into right direction!**